# What is the first child of the html element?

Tags: html, dom, document-body

[www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-body-element-0) says:

> The body element of a document is the first child of the html element

But when I check it is not a `body`, it is a `head` element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].firstElementChild
> <head>...</head>
```

Did I misunderstand anything? Because I cannot think that `w3.org` might be wrong.

Comment: You picked only the first few words of the statement! "*The body element of a document is the first child of the html element that is either a body element or a frameset element*" You may as well also read up on [`frameset` here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/obsolete.html#frameset) - *"The frameset element acts as the body element in documents that use frames."*. That is why.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is refering to what the `body` property returns, not what the content is of the `html` element.

> "The body element of a document is the first child of the html element
>   that is either a body element or a frameset element."

It means that the `body` property will return the `body` element for a regular page, because that is the first (and only) element that matches one of those types.

Answer (score 0):

i think you did not read it completely w3.org says

"The body element of a document is the first child of the html element that is either a body element or a frameset element. If there is no such element, it is null."

**if there is no such element but in your case you might have head tag**